# Order by and custom sorting in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with numeric and string values. I need to apply the custom sorting as mentioned below:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST]
(
    [Tag] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Row_Id] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_testsirius_TEST_0_Row_Id] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Row_Id] ASC)
)

Insert into TEST values (1,'Area','EMR','A',199)
Insert into TEST values (2,'Area','EMR','B',200)
Insert into TEST values (3,'Area','EMR','C',201)
Insert into TEST values (201,'Area','EMR','1',399)
Insert into TEST values (202,'Area','EMR','2',400)
Insert into TEST values (203,'Area','EMR','3',401)
```

Excepted output:

```
select * 
from TEST 
order by asc
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
A
B
C
```

Current output:

```
C
B
A
3
2
1
```

Requirement :

- If the sort direction is [↑] then first sort all the numeric values from smallest to the largest, then sort all the time values from oldest to newest and then sort all the text values from A to Z
- If the sort direction is [↓] then first sort all the text values from Z to A, then sort all the time values from newest to oldest and then sort all the numeric values from largest to the smallest
- While sorting, always place the blank cells at the bottom.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Your question is unclear!, please add more details ;).

Comment: In one table column description (varchar(max) column. I want the apply filter as mentioned below: - If the sort direction is [↑] then first sort all the numeric values from smallest to the largest, then sort all the time values from oldest to newest and then sort all the text values from A to Z
- If the sort direction is [↓] then first sort all the text values from Z to A, then sort all the time values from newest to oldest and then sort all the numeric values from largest to the smallest
- While sorting, always place the blank cells at the bottom.

Comment: I have add the requirement in Question. please go through it.

Comment: Please show the output you want for descending order and clearly _label_ that output as such.

Comment: not working for date. Please check your side

Comment: You'd be able to sort it @nirav from the examples you've been shown.

Comment: Finally I have applied below logic:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use isNumeric().

```
select * 
from TEST
order by CASE WHEN isNumeric(Description) = 1 THEN Cast([Description] as int) ELSE 2147483647 END
,   Description
```

-- for a descending order you can use the maths idea that -1 * a number maintains magnitude but reverses the order ...

```
select * 
from TEST
order by CASE WHEN isNumeric(Description) = 1 THEN Cast([Description] as int) *     -1  ELSE -2147483648 END
,   Description desc
```

-- with the extra test case for 12345

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST]
(
    [Tag] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Category] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Row_Id] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_testsirius_TEST_0_Row_Id] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Row_Id] ASC)
)

Insert into TEST values (1,'Area','EMR','A',199)
Insert into TEST values (2,'Area','EMR','B',200)
Insert into TEST values (3,'Area','EMR','C',201)
Insert into TEST values (201,'Area','EMR','1',399)
Insert into TEST values (202,'Area','EMR','2',400)
Insert into TEST values (203,'Area','EMR','3',401)
Insert into TEST values (204,'Area','EMR','12345',402)

select * 
from TEST
order by CASE WHEN isNumeric(Description) = 1 THEN Cast([Description] as int) ELSE 2147483647 END
,   Description


-- example output

Tag Category    LE  Description Row_Id
201 Area    EMR 1   399
202 Area    EMR 2   400
203 Area    EMR 3   401
204 Area    EMR 12345   402
1   Area    EMR A   199
2   Area    EMR B   200
3   Area    EMR C   201
```

-- descending order

```
select * 
from TEST
order by CASE WHEN isNumeric(Description) = 1 THEN Cast([Description] as int) * -1  ELSE -2147483648 END
,   Description desc

-- example output

Tag Category    LE  Description Row_Id
3   Area    EMR C   201
2   Area    EMR B   200
1   Area    EMR A   199
204 Area    EMR 12345   402
203 Area    EMR 3   401
202 Area    EMR 2   400
201 Area    EMR 1   399
```

Comment: HI, Please check for    "select * 
from TEST
order by CASE WHEN isNumeric(Description) = 1 THEN Cast([Description] as int) ELSE 2147483647 END
,   Description desc" not working.

Comment: I have add the requirement in Question. please go through it.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Description NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
         LEN(Description),
         Description
```

Comment: No. It's not working properly. when I insert the data 12564. it show on second line. like : 1,12564,2,3,4,A,B,C,D

Comment: @nirav If you wanted descending order, then why did you not ask this in your question?

Comment: I have add the requirement in Question. please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
select * 
from TEST 
order by case when Description not like '%[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end, Description
```

Comment: No. It's not working properly. when I insert the data 12564. it show on second line. like : 1,12564,2,3,4,A,B,C,D

Comment: I have add the requirement in Question. please go through it.